# Order results of a scope DESC

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I have this scope in my posts model

```
scope :tynewydd_posts, :include => :department, :conditions => {"departments.name" => "Ty Newydd"}
```

I want to order the returned results in the order created, so latest post first

I tried

```
scope :tynewydd_posts, :include => :department, :conditions => {"departments.name" => "Ty Newydd"}.order("posts.created_at DESC")
```

but i get undefined method order :hash, so i guess i cannot use this method here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
scope :tynewydd_posts, 
      :include => :department, 
      :conditions => {"departments.name" => "Ty Newydd"}, 
      :order => "posts.created_at DESC"
```

Answer (score 1):

`order` is a possible option to pass to the scope, so like so:

`scope :tynewydd_posts, :include => :department, :conditions => {"departments.name" => "Ty Newydd"}, :order => "posts.created_at DESC"`

Or even better, proper Rails 3 syntax like:

`scope :tynewrdd_posts, includes(:department).where('departments.name' => 'Ty Newydd').order('posts.created_at DESC')`

Comment: thank you , are there any benefits in terms of speed using the rails 3 syntax?